# How automatically split data into multiple cells using Apache poi HSSF libraries?

Tags: java, excel, jmeter, apache-poi, jsr223

I have a variable which is more than 32767 characters long and when I'm trying to write that data into a single cell using Apache poi HSSF libraries I'm getting below error
[image: Error]

How can I automatically split that data into multiple cells column wise i.e. my row should remain the same but data will be auto split into multiple column on the same row using Apache poi HSSF libraries?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's an [Excel limitation](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56579), you won't be able to overcome this.

What you can do is to split the large string and save it to the neighbor cell.

Example code:

```
def wb = new org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook()

def sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet")

def row = sheet.createRow(0)

def variable = vars.get('your-variable-name')

def chunkSize = 32767

def parts = java.util.stream.IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < variable.length(), i -> i + chunkSize)
        .mapToObj(i -> variable.substring(i, Math.min(variable.length(), i + chunkSize)))
        .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());

parts.eachWithIndex { entry, index ->
    def cell = row.createCell(index)
    cell.setCellValue(entry)
}

wb.write(new File('file.xls'))
```

More information:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)